# Turning on BBCODES - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using this chat http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/ and I tried to turn on the bbcodes but: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/bbcodes1.png/

I tried to replace in

scripts.js

```
 text       : text.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
```

with

```
text        : text.replace(/</g,'&lt;').
                                replace(/>/g,'&gt;').
                                replace(/\[b\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/b\]/,'<b>\\1</b>')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my bbcode function, you can edit the codes variable to support more bbcode. For now, it support only [b], [i], [u], [url], [img].
[read] is my special bbcode for my website

```
function bbcode(text){
    var codes = {};
    codes['url'] = {
        params : {
            href : ''
        },
        html: "<a href=\"$href\">$text</a>"
    };
    codes['b'] = {
        params : {

        },
        html : "<b>$text</b>"
    };
    codes['i'] = {
        params : {

        },
        html : "<i>$text</i>"
    };
    codes['u'] = {
        params : {

        },
        html : "<u>$text</u>"
    };
    codes['img'] = {
        params : {

        },
        html : "<img src=\"$text\" />"
    };
    codes['read'] = {
        params : {

        },
        text : function(text){
            for(var x in codes){
                text = text.replace(new RegExp('\\[' + x + '\\]','gi'), '').replace(new RegExp('\\[\\/' + x + '\\]','gi'), '');
            }
            return encodeURIComponent(text);
        },
        process: function(text){
            return text;
        },
        html : "$text <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"" + GLOBALS.baseUrl + "/player_mp3_maxi.swf\" width=\"200\" height=\"20\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"" + GLOBALS.baseUrl + "/player_mp3_maxi.swf\" /><param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#ffffff\" /><param name=\"FlashVars\" value=\"mp3=http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey%3Ddeveloperdemokeydeveloperdemokey%26action%3Dconvert%26voice%3Dusenglishfemale1%26text%3D$TEXT&amp;width=200&amp;showslider=1\" /></object>"
    };
    text = text.replace(/\</g, '&lt;').replace(/\>/g, '&gt;');
    var nomore = false;
    while(!nomore){
        var matches = text.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/gi);
        if(matches == null)
            return text;
        nomore = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
            var code = matches[i].substring(1, matches[i].length - 1);
            var parts = code.split(/\s+/);
            if(typeof codes[parts[0]] == 'object'){
                //is exist
                var obj = {};
                //get the params
                for(var j = 1; j < parts.length; j++)
                {
                    var temp = parts[j].split('=');
                    if(typeof codes[parts[0]].params[temp[0]] != 'undefined'){
                        obj[temp[0]] = (temp.length > 1) ? (temp[1].indexOf('"') == 0 ? temp[1].substring(1, temp[1].length - 1) : temp[1]) : '';

                    }
                }
                //find the text
                var index = text.indexOf(matches[i]);
                var index2 = text.indexOf('[/'+parts[0]+']', index);
                if(index2 == -1)
                    index2 = text.length;
                var t = text.substring(index + matches[i].length, index2);
                if(typeof codes[parts[0]].process == 'function'){
                    t = codes[parts[0]].process(t);
                }if(typeof codes[parts[0]].text == 'function'){
                    t2 = codes[parts[0]].text(t);
                }
                var html = codes[parts[0]].html;
                for(var x in obj)
                    html = html.replace("$" + x, obj[x]);
                html = html.replace(/\$text/g, t);
                if(typeof codes[parts[0]].text == 'function'){
                    html = html.replace(/\$TEXT/g, t2);
                }
                text = text.substr(0, index) + html + text.substr(index2 + parts[0].length + 3);
                nomore = false;
            }
        }
    }
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
    return text;
}
```

You can use this by:

```
text: bbcode(text)
```

Comment: I tried your code, for exemple [ b]something [/ b] it work but after some seconds returns without effect. :(

Comment: maybe you need to edit your php code to. I guess that this script have a function to rewrite the chat messages after `some second`, and the client-side update new messages from server -> effect was wear off